# What is the purpose of abstract in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

From the ionic provided sample starter app, we will see something like this:

```
$stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
```

What is the purpose of abstract? Comment it out, the thing still works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so you can inherit the layout of the parent state whilst navigating to the child view.

From the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views):

> An abstract state can have child states but cannot get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.

By making the state `abstract`, you prevent the ability for users to transition to that state.

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms.

`Abstract states` cannot be called. You cannot go to a url called `/tab`. Even if you try to manually enter the url on the address bar, it will lead you to a `blank` page.

Abstract states are created when you want to have child views.

For example you have a view like this.

```
.state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

We can see that `dash` is a child of a parent view called `tab` , hence the name `tab.dash`.

You'll notice that when you are at a url `/tab/dash`, The above view is loaded. But you have never defined a url called `/tab/dash` anywhere in your app. This is where abstract works. It creates a child url for your app, so don't have to write the entire url to specify a view.

So all the states that start with `tab.foo-bar` will have `/tab` prefixed to your url. Your url will become something like this.. `/tab/foo-bar`

Abstract states are mostly used when you want to have a static template as the base template, where all your other views are loaded. Its kinda like how you have those `tabs` always on your screen when you are changing urls.

If you want a detail explanation , here are some links that will help you.

1. [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)
2. [blog](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)